# Nativescript Angular ui-calendar no longer present if compile with --env.uglify

Tags: angular, nativescript

Have you ever had the problem of an element that is no longer present if you compile your application with `--env.uglify`?
I use `ui-calendar` and it is present without `uglify` but disappears with...

```
<RadCalendar #calendar locale="{{ localeCalendar }}" selectionMode="Single" viewMode="Month" (dateSelected)="updateDate($event)"></RadCalendar>
```

> Nativescript: 6.4.0
>   Nativescript Angular: 8.21.0
>   Nativescript UI Calendar: 6.1.0
>   Angular: 8.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Fix: adding the line mangle: `{ reserved: ["RadCalendar"] }` to the webpack.config.js file in `terserOptions` preserve the var name. It's work !